# Removendo maior valor da linha com for

Tags: python, pandas, for

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando extrair o maior valor inteiro de todas as linha do meu dataframe.
Criei o seguinte codigo para isso:

```
for i in df.index:
    df["maxx"] = df.loc[i].max()
    df["minn"] = df.loc[i].min()
```

O resultado esperado era gera duas colunas no dataframe (`df["maxx"] e df["minn"]`) com os seguintes valores:
max linha 1 = 23
min linha 1 = 3
max linha 2 = 78
min linha 2 = 2

Porém o resultado encontrado é:
max linha 1 = 78
min linha 1 = 2
max linha 2 = 78
min linha 2 = 2

O que devo alterar no meu codigo para considerar max e min por linha e não o dataframe total?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema utilizando o código abaixo:

```
for i in df.index:
    df["maxx"] = df.max(axis = 1)
    df["minn"] = df.min(axis = 1)
```